# How do I get time period between UTC time variables based off my local time?

Tags: javascript, utc

I am attempting to get the UTC time period between 6am - 9pm local time (I am in Southern California). My code may be completely off, but this is what I have so far:

```
var getCurrentTime = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setUTCHours(7);
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    if(h <= 16){
        do something
    }else{
        do something else
    }
};
```

Comment: How about? var d = new Date();
    d = d.setUTCHours(7);
    var h = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var h = n / 60;
    if(h <= 16){
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
var checkTime = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfMonth = d.getDate();
    var n = d.getUTCHours();
    var dayOfMonthUTC = d.getUTCDate();
    if(n >= 13 || (n <= 4 && dayOfMonthUTC === dayOfMonth + 1)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```